# RabbitMQ Atleast Once Delivery Configure Time Interval

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have read that If a consumer takes a message and does not acknowledge that it has been successfully processed within a given time window, then another consumer is given the same message to guarantee "at-least-once" delivery and I have seen this happening in our production as well.

But I would like to know is there any flag through which we can configure the time interval and only when that time period crosses re-attempt the delivery to an another consumer.

I did a lot of search but couldn't find any such flag, so if anyone who has used this property earlier, please do let me know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then another consumer is given the same message to guarantee "at-least-once" delivery

That is not true; the message remains in an un-ack'd state until the consumer acks or nacks it, or the connection to that consumer is lost; at which time the message becomes availabe to be sent to another consumer.

Comment: thanks for the revert, we read messages from queue and build docker images accordingly, sometimes the build gets stuck intermittently and it doesn't throw any exception for the DLQ to retry it , but even without any exception we have noticed that the same message is re-attempted processing by an another kubernetes pod after x no of minutes and it's continuing like this and I have checked the rabbitMQ logs, the cluster is healthy and the service also didn't throw any exception, so not sure why message retries are happening, can you think of any other reason for this kind of behavior ...thanks

Comment: There is no mechanism to requeue a message aside from what I described above.